# Normal Map causes mesh to darken in certain areas

Tags: texturing, normals, normal-map

My mesh is purely sculpted and I did not bake any normal map from it. However, I did import the mesh into Quixel Mixer to get some textures on it and exported those texture files to use back in blender. In Mixer it looked perfect. However, it turned some faces slightly darker when in blender and after playing around, I noticed it was the normal map that was causing this. I tried changing the normal map to be from tangent space to object space, which seemed to do the trick in the shader tab but back in the layout tab, it looked completely dark. I intend to use these for UE, but I'm not sure if this would affect how it appears in UE. I've attached some photos to hopefully identify the problem, thanks in advance! (the arrows in the photos are just showing the places where the colours no longer match up)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are your normals all facing the correct directions? You can check using the overlays. Or, if you're feeling bold, in edit mode, select all > mesh > normals > recalculate outside.

Comment: On further thought, another issue that could cause this is a non-uniform scale on the object. Enter object mode > ctrl+a > Scale